# How to update Read and Delivery status of sent and received messages using Quickblox IOS?

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone, quickblox

I have implemented a chat sample app using Quickblox,And I followed SampleChat app provided by Quckblox(Urls provided below). But I want to update Read and Delivery status of each message. How to achieve this?

1. http://quickblox.com/developers/SimpleSample-chat_users-ios
2. https://github.com/QuickBlox/quickblox-ios-sdk/tree/master/sample-chat

In link 1 they have explained some code but I'm unable to implement.

Comment: Quickblox is already provide the status of Read and Unread status

Comment: There is no such sample code is implemented, I tried to implement but its not working

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are docs for [read](http://quickblox.com/developers/SimpleSample-chat_users-ios#Read_status) and [delivered](http://quickblox.com/developers/SimpleSample-chat_users-ios#Delivered_status) status in the link you provided.

To make this answer more explicit, there are several ways to mark messages as read and delivered. For delivered marking there is only XMPP way available, use this method from QBChat to do it:

```
/**
 *  Send "delivered" status for message.
 *
 *  @param message      QBChatMessage message to mark as delivered.
 *  @param completion   Completion block with failure error.
 */
- (void)markAsDelivered:(QB_NONNULL QBChatMessage *)message completion:(QB_NULLABLE QBChatCompletionBlock)completion;
```

For read marker you can use either REST request using QBRequest method:

```
/**
 Mark messages as read.

 @note Updates message "read" status only on server.

 @param dialogID dialog ID.
 @param messagesIDs Set of chat message IDs to mark as read. If messageIDs is nil then all messages in dialog will be marked as read.
 @param successBlock Block with response instance if request succeded.
 @param errorBlock Block with response instance if request failed.
 @return An instance, which conforms Cancelable protocol. Use this instance to cancel the operation.
 */
+ (QB_NONNULL QBRequest *)markMessagesAsRead:(QB_NONNULL NSSet QB_GENERIC(NSString *) *)messagesIDs
                                    dialogID:(QB_NONNULL NSString *)dialogID
                                successBlock:(QB_NULLABLE void(^)(QBResponse * QB_NONNULL_S response))successBlock
                                  errorBlock:(QB_NULLABLE QBRequestErrorBlock)errorBlock;
```

or XMPP method of QBChat:

```
/**
 *  Send "read" status for message and update "read" status on a server
 *
 *  @param message      QBChatMessage message to mark as read.
 *  @param completion   Completion block with failure error.
 */
- (void)readMessage:(QB_NONNULL QBChatMessage *)message completion:(QB_NULLABLE QBChatCompletionBlock)completion;
```

Anyway look closer to samples and documentation if you need a "live" example.

Comment: Actually I'm using QMChat View Controller ,QMServices so these call backs are handled by them. And my doubt is how to know weather this perticuler message is deleivered or read or not. I want to know this status in my model(QMChatSectionManager *chatSectionManager) or (QBChatMessage *message) how to know this ?

Comment: See QBChat delegates. You can subscribe to them whenever you want.

Comment: Hi sir, I have a requirement, I want to upload profile image for each quick blox user and from there it should be shown to other user who wants to  create a chat dialog with the first user I saw sample-content example provided. But here my scenario is different So could you help me please

Comment: In examples they are uploading a file with content type or updating existing file. But how this can be accessed by other users to show image. and even if we provide public as 'yes'. How other user can see the actual users pic. And how the current user has to upload the image and where ? so much confusion sir please help me

Comment: This is my mail ID myiosgallery@gmail.com

Comment: See [Q-municate](https://github.com/QuickBlox/q-municate-ios) project. It has user avatars and you can use it as an example :)

Comment: This is what i tried http://stackoverflow.com/questions/37043763/how-to-upload-the-users-profile-pic-and-how-to-fetch-that-profile-pic-from-anoth?noredirect=1#comment61637114_37043763 but still I'm unable to get the image

Comment: Please can you look at this http://stackoverflow.com/q/40755187/3144836