# How to update a sent message in Quickblox IOS

Tags: ios, swift, quickblox

How do I update a sent QBChatMessage in the server? For e.g. After the message is sent/delivered, how does one update it's text or custom parameters. Also are there parameters that cannot be changed or updated once sent and delivered?

Here's a [link to the snippet](http://quickblox.com/developers/Android_XMPP_Chat_Sample#Update_chat_messages) on Quickblox Android that seems to be doing the same. How is this achieved in IOS?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There is a method in QBRequest:

```
/**
 Update existing chat message - mark it as read.

 @param message Сhat message to update.
 @param successBlock Block with response instance if request succeded.
 @param errorBlock Block with response instance if request failed.

 @return An instance of QBRequest for cancel operation mainly.
 */
+ (QBRequest *)updateMessage:(QBChatMessage *)message
                successBlock:(nullable void(^)(QBResponse *response))successBlock
                  errorBlock:(nullable QBRequestErrorBlock)errorBlock;
```

The usage is the same as in android pretty much. Here you can read which fields you can update: http://quickblox.com/developers/Chat#Fields_to_update_2